# App Termination while paused for debugging in Visual Studio MAUI

Tags: ios, visual-studio, maui

I have a C# MAUI App.
The App partial class is trivial

```
public partial class App : Application {public App() {AppData.Init();}}
```

I need to debug the Init() function, deployed to a local iPhone.

However, when I hit a debug breakpoint in Init(), after ~10 seconds something happens and the App is immediately terminated, even though it is ostensibly paused for debugging. Which makes debugging challenging.

The issue seems to be maybe related to HotReload, but I have disabled HotReload under VS.Tools.Options.Debugging.XAMLHotReload and under VS.Tools.Options.Debugging..NET/C++HotReload.

This is Windows VS 17.7.0 Preview 4.0. Same behavior on VS Stable.
Not sure what to try next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Mobile OS's terminate an app if the first page doesn't display within ~10 seconds.
- For testing purposes, change your approach. Make an empty page appear (or any page that does not need AppData.Init). In that page's `Constructor` or `OnAppearing`, delay slightly so page can appear, then do the needed Init.

In App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new TestPage();   // NOT AppShell (for this test).
}
```

In TestPage.xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage
    ...
    x:Class="YourProject.TestPage" >

    <Label Text="This is a test..." />

</ContentPage>
```

In TestPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
public TestPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // This code runs in background, after TestPage constructor returns.
        await Task.Delay(1000);   // Because we are breakpointing in Init code, make sure page has appeared first. Delay can be shorter.
        AppData.Init();
        Dispatcher.Dispatch( () => 
        {
            // This code runs on UI thread.
            Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();   // Create and show Shell here.
        });
    });
}
```

I specify not initializing AppShell, because that will create pages for your tabs. Your pages might depend on initialization in your Init method.

I've shown AppData.Init running on a background thread.

NOTE: "TestPage" could be replaced with a "Login" Page, if appropriate.
In that case, the `new AppShell` line would be done after a successful Login.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean here? "Mobile OS's terminate an app if the first page doesn't display within". I've been a mobile developer since 2016 and haven't known this to be an issue. Do you mean on iOS? Or Android too?

Comment: I test on iOS and this is True fact. @Chucky